# How come that if Ax = W is consistent than a vector w is part of the Im A.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a matrix A and a vector w and I want to verify that w is included in the Im A, Why is solving [ A | w ] and it giving a solution (being consistent) prove that w is include in Im A?  I am also not sure what consistent even means.

Comment: How do you define the image/column space of a matrix? Also, consistency of a linear system of equations is covered in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_and_inconsistent_equations).

Comment: "$Ax = w$ is consistent" is _defined_ as "$Ax = w$ has a solution", i.e., "There is a vector $x$ such that $Ax = w$", that is, $w \in \operatorname{Im} A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix equation $Ax = w$ is consistent if it has at least one solution $x$.  If any solutions $x$ exist, then $w$ is in the image, or range of the matrix $A$.  Think of the matrix $A$ as a function that maps a vector $x$ to another vector $w$.  The output $w$ must be in the image of $A$.